# Executing a function after page loaded - JQuery

Tags: jquery

Using the following:

```
function loadDefault() {
    //default text of "Place Text Here"
    alert("working");
    $(".Singleshell:first").trigger('click');
}
$(window).load(function () {
  //initilize default option

    loadDefault();
});
```

Does not seem to work for me for some reason.  I have tried placing the `.load` function inside a ready statement and to alert out `alert("working")` but it does not seem to execute properly.  I am not getting an type of error message that I can see.  It never loads the `loadDefault()` function.

Curious to why this is, let me know your ideas?

UPDATE;

I am also using the `$(document).ready()` - this worked, however when it would cause a click, the function that is suppose to execute would not work correctly.  I believe this was due to other sources where still loading.

UPDATE:

I am actually thinking about using `window.setTimeout(loadDefault, 1000);` it seems to work but I am not sure if this is a safe way to go?

Comment: Just use `$(document).ready(function (){ /* your code here */ });`

Comment: Check update I just made.

Comment: You're saying you `.trigger('click');` doesn't work when you use `$(document).ready()`?  If so, try changing to `.click()`.  Also, post your actual code with `$(document).ready()` or put up a jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @user1477388 no, i think he means that the document has to be loaded in order for this to work on that specific element.

Comment: @DavidBiga this should work there is no way anyone can figure this out with the information provided, because there is nothing that is wrong.

Comment: Ya so here is what happens.  This is a big selection type preview system I have built and I am setting default values for the user and so if I just instantly run the loadDefault() it does not seem to work because probably, other sources still need to execute.

Comment: @Connor the actual clicking is not working though.  Because I have different fields and each one is associated with a .php and .js file that will populate the fields appropriately.  So if one has not loaded yet and that instantly runs, it will not execute because it does not exist.

Comment: A good start would be to get the alert working, then worry about the clicking

Comment: @user1477388 there is a big difference between `load` & `ready` if you didn't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
window.onload = loadDefault;
```

If that works then maybe you have a problem with jQuery not executing the load function

The `onload` event is cross browser so just use that.

If that doesn't work then the last suggestion i have is

```
document.body.onload = loadDefault;
```

Comment: Hey Connor check my update in question about the timer.  It seems to work but I am not sure if this is a quality way to go?

Comment: Yes but who is to say that everything will load within 1 second

Comment: Ya I know, everything does at the moment.

Comment: I decided to go with the timer for your's is not working but I will give you it because it is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need to do is have a list of events that the overall page has to listen for.  So after the last event is fired, only then run the code in question.  So if you have 10 panels, all opening various web pages asynchronously, you'll need an array of 10 true/false load complete flags or some such...

Note: jQuery has an Ajax stop event you can use.  So if loading all the panels via jQuery or Ajax, can check for that.  http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: I could go that way or I could probably just plug in at the end of the last file source given to probably?

Comment: That assumes you know which one will be last.  If async, you don't have that luxury.